# Real function with intermediate value property and one more property as set $\{x:f(x)=r\}$ is always closed for every rational $r$, is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

This is exercise $19$ from fourth chapter of baby Rudin.

Suppose $f$ is a real function with domain $R^1$ which has IVP i.e. if $f(a) < c < f(b)$, then $f(x)=c$ for some $x$ between $a$ and $b$. Suppose also for every rational $r$, that the set of all $x$ with $f(x)=r$ is closed. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

I use the hint given by author and got the answer. You can look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/355903/409319).

When I was thinking about this problem, I drew some graphs. One of the graph I draw has puzzled me. It seems to satisfy both the hypotheses, but fails to be continuous.
The graph is as follows.
[image]

Graph seems to satisfy IVP and also any horizontal line $y=k$ will hit graph at most twice, so second hypotheses also seems to satisfy. But $f$ is not continuous at origin. What I am messing up here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does *not* satisfy the intermediate value property: $f(0)=3$ and $f(-1)<2$, but there is no $a\in(-1,0)$ such that $f(a)=2$.

Comment: I overlooked the condition $f(x)=c$ **for some x between a and b**. Thanks. Just a small question. Was there anything special about rationals in second hypothesis or we can just take any dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Any dense subset of $\Bbb R$ will do.

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not satisfy IVP for $[-x_{0},x_{0}]$ and $c=2$ if $x_{0}$ is small enough.